# generating errors with heteroscedasticity

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I have a question regarding generating errors with heteroscedasticity

This is how my friend told me to do it:

```
n <- 30  
x1 <- rnorm(n,0,1) # 1st predictor 
x2 <- rnorm(n,0,1)  # 2nd predictor   
e <- rnorm(n,0,x1^2)  # errors with heteroscedaticity     
b1 <- 0.5; b2 <- 0.5     
y <- x1*b1+x2*b2+e
```

For me, `e <-rnorm(n,0,x1^2)` -- this is autocorrelation rather than heteroscedastic error distribution. 
But my friend said this is the correct way to generate errors with heteroscedasticity.

Am I missing something here?

I thought heteroscedasticity occurs when the variance of the error terms differ across observations.

Does `e<-rnorm(n,0,x1^2)` this syntax generate errors with heteroscedasticity correctly?

If not, could anyone tell me how to generate errors with heteroscedasticity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specification does generate a particular (slightly odd) kind of heteroscedasticity. You define heteroscedasticity as "the variance of the error term differ[ing] across observations". Since the value of `x1` is different for different observations, and you have chosen your error values with a standard deviation of `x1^2`, the variances will be different for different observations.

note that

- `rnorm()` specifies variability in terms of the standard deviation rather than the variance
- autocorrelation refers to non-independence between (successive) observations. `rnorm()` chooses independent deviates, so this specification doesn't constitute an autocorrelated sample.